# javascript chinese/japanese character decoding

Tags: javascript, utf-8, decode

I created a JSONP function on the server and returns a UTF-8 encoded json object like this

```
applyLocalization({"Name":"%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D","Age":"%E5%B9%B4%E9%BD%A2"});
```

on my javascript on the client side, i want to convert the garbled part to their original state like

```
{"Name":"名前", "Age":"年齢"}
```

I tried $.parseJSON() but it doesnt work

Comment: How are you encoding the text on the server? There's a JSON standard for encoding UTF-8, which looks different...

Comment: what i do is i encode the key and the value by using URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8") function in java. is there any otherway?

Comment: What about using a JSON encoding function. I am not a Java guy, but a function that can take a native array and spit out the JSON equivalent exists for virtually every language...

Comment: actually this is what i do... i read a file written in japanese and what i do is i create a JSON object in java and put a key and the value (which is in japanese), but before i put it i encode it using the URLEncoder then the result is like this {"Name":"%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D","Age":"%E5%B9%B4%E9%BD%A2"}.... then i send this to the client and thats where i plan to decode it using decodeURIComponent as what the fellas below said

Comment: Why don't you skip the URL encoding? Then there's also no need to URL decode it.

Comment: tried it but gives me question marks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `decodeURIComponent` to decode urlencoded strings like yours

```
decodeURIComponent('%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D');
//result: '名前'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function. But you shouldn't be URL encoding your javascript strings. You should send them as UTF-8 strings as-is. Javascript is capable of understanding them.

Comment: i tried to send them as is but the japanese part become series of question marks so i decided to encode them then decode on the client... is there anything wrong?

Comment: @ChinchanZu, yes there must be something wrong with your page or server. Maybe you are no setting the correct response content type or maybe your page is not correctly encoded.